# No error for extern variable redefined as static

Tags: c, static, extern

I wrote the following code:

```
//f1.h
extern uint8 yyy;

//f1.c
#include "f1.h"
uint8 yyy;
...
//many more variables created by previous developers
static uint8 yyy; //created by previous developers
...
```

I assumed the previous developers had not named such a variable and created yyy.
After some code review changes, I decided to rename yyy to something else and while searching f1.c for yyy, i found another static variable in f1.c as

```
static uint8 yyy;
```

Why didn the compiler warn me about another variable yyy initially?

While performing a Lint of the file, Lint just gives a warning:

```
Warning 401: symbol 'yyy' not previously declared static at line.
```

Assuming I had no Lint, is it OK to declare a static and a extern variable with the same name? 
What checks can I do to ensure that a variable name does'nt already exist while creating a new variable?

Comment: Are both declarations at file scope? Which declaration appears first in the translation unit?

Comment: It is an error to have a declaration with `extern` followed by a declaration with `static` for the same variable in the same scope;  if you didn't see a compiler error it suggests the code was not actually as you describe. (E.g. perhaps f1.c does not include f1.h)

Comment: What compiler? `gcc` gives a [fatal error](https://pastebin.com/raw/1xKpbyKi). Tested using `gcc (Ubuntu 4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04.3) 4.8.4`.

Comment: @ikegami You're assuming `f1.c` includes `f1.h`.

Comment: @melpomene, No, In addition to the OP saying both declarations exist, `lint` shows it to be included.

Comment: `static uint8 yyy.` is a syntax error, it would help to post real code. In particular it is important whether or not there is an initializer

Comment: @Akshay Immanuel D, Could you show that `f1.c` includes `include `#include "f1.h"` as it's rather relevant.

Comment: @ikegami There are three declarations. One in the header and two in the .c file.

Comment: Why was this downvoted as not related to programming?

Comment: No lint? Use gcc. It's free.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the code you're describing (`uint8 yyy; static uint8 yyy;`) has undefined behavior. C99, **6.2.2 Linkages of identifiers**:

> 3. If the declaration of a file scope identifier for an object or a function contains the storage-class specifier `static`, the identifier has internal linkage.
>
> 5. [...] If the declaration of an identifier for an object has file scope and no storage-class specifier, its linkage is external.
>
> 7. If, within a translation unit, the same identifier appears with both internal and external linkage, the behavior is undefined.

I.e. a compiler error is not required.

Comment: Hmm.. thats a pretty big problem because I cant keep a track of all the variable used by previous developers. Is there any check I can perform like an assert to check if no other variable exists with the same name?

Comment: Re "*thats a pretty big problem*", Why? You just said you could use `lint` to find instances of this.

Comment: @AkshayImmanuelD "*I cant keep a track of all the variable used by previous developers*" ... Why do you have so many global variables in your code base? Also, can't you just do a quick search for any variable name you want to introduce to see whether it's already in use?

Comment: There are ways in my code: Lint,Manual search. I want to be independent of such manual tests and make sure anyone else creating a new variable chooses something not used already. Is there any way possible ?

Comment: @AkshayImmanuelD, The call to `lint` doesn't have to be manual. You could include it in your makefile.

Comment: That's not the point. Assuming No Lint(i cant afford it,Im just a hobbyist programmer wanting to write safe code). Can i write a code that checks for duplicate variable names(sort of like a static assert for structures).